# Row to Columns in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

This seems like it should be exceedingly easy and yet I have not found an example after much searching. I would like to take data in an access database like this:

```
Product | Code
1000    | 120055
1000    | 3456
1000    | 4589 
1000    | 8097
2000    | 154631
2000    | 5646
2000    | 6254
```

And make it look like this with a query.

```
Product | Code 1  | Code 2 | Code 3 | Code 4
1000    | 120055  | 3456   | 4589   | 8097
2000    | 154631  | 5646   | 6254   |
```

If there are ten codes for a certain product I would need to have a 10 columns labeled "code 1" through "code 10"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a crosstab query in Access. Please read this article: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx